# code for a website welcome page using function in C (not executing properly)

Tags: c, function, error-handling, user-defined-functions

```
#include<stdio.h>
void welcome ();
void welcome(){printf("welcome to our company");}
void query();
void query(){printf ("hello, how can i help you with today?\n");}
void endig();
void ending(){printf("our sales executive will contact you soon\n");}

int main()
{
    char name,prob;
    void welcome();
    printf("please help us with your name \n");
    scanf("%c",&name);
    void query();
    scanf("%c",&prob);
    void ending();
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting all the functions to print along with the code written in main function. But only help us with your name is showing up.

Comment: Calling a function is `welcome();`, not `void welcome();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try expanding your code and making it more readable, I couldn't find the issue in your code but I did write a formatted version.

One thing I did do that is different from yours is using `scanf` to get %s rather than getting %c.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void welcome();
void welcome()
{
    printf("Welcome to our company!");
}

int main()
{
    char name, prob;
    void welcome();
    printf("Please help us with your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    welcome();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested, works on my end.